# How to create an attachment field for SharePoint form in React with browse and drag-and-drop options?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm currently working on a React application that integrates with SharePoint, and I'm trying to implement an attachment field within a form. I'd like to provide users with the flexibility to either browse their computer for the file or use drag-and-drop to upload attachments.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this functionality. Specifically, I'm looking for assistance with the following:

1. How can I create an attachment field using React that's compatible with SharePoint?
2. What is the best approach to include a browse option that allows users to select a file from their computer?
3. Are there any recommended techniques or libraries to implement drag-and-drop functionality for uploading attachments?

I'm open to code examples, libraries, tutorials, or any other resources that can help me accomplish this task. Thank you in advance for your insights and assistance!

Asking for direction